# Expose cobolfiles db using webservices or API

Tags: api, web-services, soap, cobol

I have to expose data of an old application through webservices or API for manage data and interface a new python app whit it. I know that is a COBOL application, i found this documentation:

[Introduction to COBOL Web Services](https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/nx50/dwwint.htm)

I don't have experience with cobol; someone can guide me through the best choise for expose cobol data using webservices for example?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Which COBOL compiler / environment exactly do you use? Can you compile and run new COBOL programs?

Comment: It is Suse linux enterprise 2.627. thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "cobol data". It is just data. The language used to produce it is irrelevant. You can use any language you like to access the data - all you need to know is the record definition(s).

Comment: Ok, we now know what OS you have. What COBOL compiler is used? Can you compile and run new programs? Do you know how the data access is defined (in COBOL look for the [`SELECT` statement](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#select))

Comment: The only think i know is that i don't find a real db but a list of files that should contain data. i would to create a webservices, for example using WSDL from the cobol program for expose the data contained in these file and gave me access through POST and GET HTTP calls...fo example

Comment: What is the file format?  It really doesn't matter if it's written by COBOL, C, or ??  The COBOL program might help with the file layout through PIC statements.  Other than that you really don't need to know COBOL for this. The webservices document you linked is to connect a COBOL program through the service.  It is not needed for this.

Comment: The only thing we now is what you want to achieve but we cannot guess at all how to do this as long as we don't know what files you have that you want to access. If it is a COBOL INDEXED file you really would better "manage data" (which I understand as not only query but also adjust/add) on the COBOL side, but... we still don't know. Missing information: `SELECT` statement (to know at least *what* kind of data you have) and which COBOL environment is currently used to work with the data. You may log on to the system and execute `cob -V` and `cobc -v` to check for two common environments.